# How to validate page title is correct actual to expected selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written a very basic selenium test. My test returns the page title of a page but if i wanted to go one step further now and validate the page title against what i was expecting how would i do this?

So for example if i expected the title to be "aaa" but it's returning something different i want my test to fail.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class test1
    {
                static void Main()
            { 
                IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity");
                webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                String title = webDriver.Title;
                Console.WriteLine("Title of webpage is " + title);
               // webDriver.Quit();
        }

        }   
    }
```

Comment: You need to use something like NUnit library (google it) for this, read about how to use Assert. In your case it will be like: Assert.AreEqual("expectedTitle", title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare it like,

```
String expectedTitle = "Utilities from Go Compare";
if(title.contains(expectedTitle)){
   Console.writeline("Title is matching with expected value");
}
else{
   Console.writeline("Title is not matching with expected value");
}
```

or you can use `NUnit` Assert methods like

```
Assert.AreEqual(true, title.contains(expectedTitle), "Title is not matching");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
String expectedtitle = "type expected title";

String actualtitle = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("copy xpath perticuler title")).Text.ToString();

Assert.AreEqual(expectedtitle, actualtitle);
```