# Handle an exception in IF statement c# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written code with an IF statement. But all my statement currently does is output whether or not the text I'm expecting is correct or not.

How can I change the implementation so that if the title isn't matching to what I expect the test stops and fails?

```
 String title = webDriver.Title;

 String expectedTitle = "Utilities from Go Compare";
 if (title.Contains(expectedTitle))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Tile is matching with expected value");
 }
 else
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Tile is not matching");
 }
```

Comment: I don't see any loop here

Comment: Do you mean you want to **throw** an exception if the title doesn't match? This could be done with the [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw) expression.

Comment: as I say before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282067/how-to-validate-page-title-is-correct-actual-to-expected-selenium-c-sharp#comment89542003_51282067 you need to use NUnit for this. This is a library for write tests. Example here https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-webdriver-csharp-nunit/

Comment: Yes that's what i want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a Test Method you should throw an exception or use the "Assert" class as follows:

```
String title = webDriver.Title;
String expectedTitle = "Utilities from Go Compare";

bool ignoreCase = ...;
Assert.AreEqual(title, expectedTitle, ignoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String title = webDriver.Title;
String expectedTitle = "Utilities from Go Compare";

if (title.Contains(expectedTitle))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Title is matching with expected value");
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Title does not match");
}
```

or in a `[TestMethod]`:

```
String title = webDriver.Title;
String expectedTitle = "Utilities from Go Compare";

bool contains = title.Contains(expectedTitle);
Assert.IsTrue(contains);
```

Comment: Perfect i've opted to go with the first suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use assert on you verification point, if assert conditions is not matching assert will throw exception :

String expectedTitle = "Utilities from Go Compare";

// 1st Way
bool isTrue= webDriver.Title.Contains(expectedTitle);
Assert.IsTrue(isTrue);

OR 

// 2nd Way
Assert.Contains(expectedTitle,webDriver.Title);
```